# How to find approximate coordinates from four different lists od coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have four lists representing X and Y coordinates of different points in lists A and B so X_A, Y_A, X_B, Y_B

```
A ] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
X_A = [1.0, 2.2, 3.0, 4.0, 5.001, 6.0]
Y_A = [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.1, 8.0, 0.0]
B = ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
X_B = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0005, 7.0, 9.1, 11.0]
Y_B = [0.0, 1.0, 8.0, 2.0, 8.0, 0.1]
```

The above is read as 'a' has coordinates (1.0, 0.0) and 'l' has coordinates (3.0, 1.0)

I would like to add items from A to Node_A list and items from B to Node_B the corresponding coordinates of the elements of lists A and B satisfy an error margin:

```
(X_A - X_B) <= error and (Y_A - Y_B) <= error
```

I have the below code which I believe should be doing the job but it does not seem to work and I don't understand why, any help is appreciated!

```
Node_A, Node_B = [], []

error = 1e-2

i, j = 0, 0
for lo1,la1 in zip(X_A, Y_A):
    for lo2,la2 in zip(X_B, Y_B):
        if abs(lo1 - lo2) <= error and abs(la1 == la2) <= error:
            Node_A.append(A[i])
            Node_B.append(B[j])
            break
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0
```

The desired output should be as below as they 'a' coordinates from A equal 'k' coordinates from B and 'e' coordinates satisfy the error margin and thus approximately equal to 'm' coordinates:

```
Node_A: ['a', 'e']
Node_B: ['k', 'm']
```

Instead I get Node_A: ['c'] and Node_B: ['l']

Comment: This is not a good way of storing this data. Have you ever tried object oriented programming? What is your current result?

Comment: You have a `==` in your `if` that should be a minus. The code works.

Comment: Are you sure about `abs(la1 == la2)` , Maybe this needs to be `abs(la1 - la2)` instead?

Comment: I believe you have some typos on your code, such as `A ] ['a', ...` => `A = ['a', ...` or defining `X_A = [1.0 2.2 ` => `X_A = [1.0, 2.2, ...`

Comment: Thank you, sorry for wasting your time this was a dumb post

Comment: Typo error. Works if you replace `la1 == la2` by `la1 - la2`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 if abs(lo1 - lo2) <= error and abs(la1 == la2) <= error:
```

to

```
 if abs(lo1 - lo2) <= error and abs(la1 - la2) <= error:
```

Result:

```
['a', 'e']
['k', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the second condition.

This gives you a:e,k:m:

```
i, j = 0, 0
for lo1,la1 in zip(X_A, Y_A):
    for lo2,la2 in zip(X_B, Y_B):
        if abs(lo1 - lo2) <= error and abs(la1 - la2) <= error:
            Node_A.append(A[i])
            Node_B.append(B[j])
            break
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0
```